# enable button from other uiview controller class

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying enable button from uiviewcontroller class of other uiviewcontroller but i cant able to enable it. Here is code that i am doing

```
@implementation InAppClass
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction 
{    

if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:idstring])
  {               
  generateAdviceViewController *objgenerate= [[generateAdviceViewController alloc]init ];
    [objgenerate enableDisableMethod];
    [objgenerate release];
   }
}
@end

@implementation generateAdviceViewController
-(id)enableDisableMethod
{
[self->generateButton setEnabled:TRUE];
return self;
}
@end
```

Am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you enabling generate button before generateAdviceViewController's view is loaded... Refer to this view after you created generateAdviceViewController like this:

```
[objgenerate view];
```

And then call enableDisableMethod.

The code looks strange. Is it just example?